# merge two rows into one sql

Tags: sql, merge, dbeaver

this is my table schema,  total_hours column is the result of a sum function.

```
Id  name    client  total_hours
1   John    company 1   100
1   John    company 2   200
2   Jack    company 3   350
2   Jack    company 2   150
```

I want to merge the rows with similar ID into one row, looking like this.

```
    Id  name    client_a    total_hours_a   client_b    total_hours_b
     1  John    company 1    100            company 2    200
     2  Jack    company 3    350            company 2    150
```

I tried to use pivot but this function does not seem to exist in Dbeaver. Here is my query

```
 SELECT 
   client
   ,name
   ,sum(hours) AS total_hours
 FROM pojects 
 GROUP BY client, name;
```

Thanks in advance if anyone could be of any help.

Comment: Is there any column that can represent the order for `a` or `b`?

Comment: No, the order for companies is random. The goal is to have one row for each ID/name (employee) with the clients they work on. Their similarity lies within the employee.